# ON/OFF switch for smoke simulation effectors

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm doing a test on a project with different field effects,"WIND ,VORTEX ,TURBULENCE ... etc." and I would like to try each effector independently of each other without having to delete other effectors in the scene.

Is there a simple on and off mechanism for an effector that will disable unwanted effectors?

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the *Field Weights* section of the domain object's physics panel.

There are dials for each type of field, which you can set to 0.0 for OFF and 1.0 for ON.

Another way is to create a collection and seet the effector collections. Put the active field effector in that collection, all other effectors will be ignored for the purposes of the smoke simulation.  Then swap out the effector when you want to change to another field effect.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: hello, very complicated the "blender" system when wants to do for example a "test" between several "simulation object", why not do as in music software or video editing, simply add a "MUTE" button and "SOLO" to each simulation or various effects object (I have been a musician for 40 years) example add a button "ctrl M" and "ctrl S" in "Scene collection"> "filter"
to "activate" deactivate ", thank you

Comment: The key bindings you suggest are already used for mirror and snap.  The weight controls provide analogue granularity.  You can always customize the UI with Python.  Your use-case is specific and would not help animators of more complex simulations.  From one musician to another, think of these as volume controls on a mixer if you prefer.  Feel free to upvote and mark as accepted solution.